# wamp server wordpress media library not showing images

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wamp

Im running wordpress woocommerce website on localhost via Wamp Server. The media library once worked fine but right now, every time I upload a new picture, the thumbnail doesn't show but when I open the url of the file location, the picture shows well.

I tried deactivating all the plugins but the issue is still the same.

I also tried other solutions like reuploading my .htaccess but its not working.

Please help me out.

Comment: any error on console log?

Comment: This is what I got in my console as I inspect in my media library page ---> Active resource loading counts reached a per-frame limit while the tab was in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is brought to the foreground. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more detailsn 1.4.1
wp-tinymce.php?ver=4800-20180716:2

Comment: I found out that the permalink and the file url of the image is different. Permalink is http://localhost:8080/furniture/logobcss/ and the file url is http://localhost:8080/furniture/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/logoBCSS-4.png

Comment: Update site URL & Home URL and save permalink it'll work

Comment: I'm using ciya shop for woocommerce.

Comment: It was working well yesterday, but today not anymore. I added the photos here for you to see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZCVlQv3Q22MLCKmMGvCpT210m0xt8pob

Comment: @GroupOfOceninfo what do you mean by updating urls and permalink? The site is running locally using wamp server :(

Comment: @vel 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /furniture/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /furniture/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress



php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300

Comment: and did you try with small images? I mean less than 1 MB and 72dpi

Comment: @Vel I tried uploading 12.4 KB still not working

Comment: @Vel How can I share my files with you?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Inspect Element and check if the path of your images are correct or not. If there something wrong with the path of the images, then fix with inserting the images into the folder C:\wamp\www.

This way your Wampserver will find the images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried opening the url http://localhost:8080/furniture/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/typing.png it shows perfectly. I noticed that when I open the picture in the media library it goes like this      

File name:
File type: image/png
Uploaded on: 25th January 2019
File size:

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** Login to Wordpress Backend

**Step 2** Go to > Settings > General Settings

**Step 3** Supply WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) to your local website URL i.e. http://localhost:8080/furniture and Save changes

**Step 4** Go to > Settings > Permalink Settings scroll down to Product permalinks and select **Shop base** and Save changes

Hard refresh and Test your product page it should have to work normally.

If above solution is not working for you then you can disable all plugin and use default theme might be incompatible plugin or incorrect file permissions are the primary causes here as I have seen you're not able to see Grid View properly.

Comment: I tried but I noticed in the permalink settings everytime I save changes it will always go back to custom base :(

Comment: That's normal once you selected shop base and save changes, Radio button will move to custom base. Try to disable plugin and theme might be there's something getting conflict or permission issue

Comment: I tried deactivating all the plugins and reset to default theme but the issue is still there